# Python Pydantic double base model

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI with Pydantic and I'm trying to achieve that my API accepts cammel case parameters, for this, I'm using the following

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from humps import camelize


class CamelModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        alias_generator = camelize
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


class MyClass(CamelModel):
    my_field1: int
    my_field2: int
    my_field3: int
```

So far it works great, but MyClass is a base class for others classes, for example as

```
class MyNewClass(MyClass):
    my_field4: float
```

How can I get the MyNewClass to also use the camel case base class? I've tried something like

```
from typing import Union 
class MyNewClass(Union[MyClass, CamelModel]):
    my_field4: float
```

But I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot subclass <class 'typing._SpecialForm'>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called `multiple inheritance`. Since you are inheriting from a class which inherited from the CamelModel, there's no need to inherit it again

The appropriate code should be

`class MyNewClass(MyClass):`

It's the python syntax for multiple inheritance. See an extensive example here https://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance_example.php#An-Example-of-Multiple-Inheritance

The code you are using (`class MyNewClass(Union[MyClass, CamelModel]):`) is used for declaring data types, which is kinda of correct, but not in the right place. Typing is almost only (as far as I've seen) used for parameters of functions.

**NOTE**
I did not test the piece of code above, but I'm pretty sure it works. Let me know if there are any problems

Comment: You are right, this is just class inheritance, this way should work just fine, thanks for the response!

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please mark the answer as accepted, so that it will not appear as open.